# Weird characters when fetching and saving value in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Every time i use a apostrophe in my query its saving with a Backslash. I'm saving everything in UTF-8.

This is my code

```
$mysqli->escape_string($_POST['title']);
```

And I also tried

```
$mysqli->escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['title']));
```

But every time its saving Backslash and apostrophe \'

Can anyone point me out the problem. Also this is not happning on my localhost while using xampp for windows. its happening in my hosting server which is bluehost.

Comment: It's possible that they have [`magic_quotes`](http://www.php.net/magic_quotes) enabled. Check with `phpinfo()`.

Comment: You can avoid this escaping hassle by passing your variables to MySQL by way of [parameters to prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496).

Comment: @eggyal it won't solve the very problem with magic quotes though

Comment: @YourCommonSense: True (assuming, of course, that the problem in this case is indeed `magic_quotes`).